# SQLite SELECT * FROM кодировка

Tags: sqlite

Здравствуйте. Есть две программы: **command-line shell** и **DB browser for SQLite**. Вот скрипт.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Words (
 id_Words INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 en TEXT NOT NULL,
 ru TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Words (en, ru) VALUES
 ('one', 'один'),
 ('two', 'два'),
 ('three', 'три'),
 ('four', 'четыре'),
 ('five', 'пять');

SELECT * FROM Words;
```

Если я выполняю этот скрипт в DB browser for SQLite, вывод русских слов происходит нормально, как в этой программе, так и в command-line shell. 
Но, когда я выполняю этот скрипт в command-line shell, вывод русских слов происходит не корректно, вместо букв, знаки вопросов. Подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: что именно подразумевается под «command-line shell»?

Comment: Уважаемый Fat-Zer, подразумевается коммандная строка.

Comment: мм... скорей всего какие-то виндовые заморочки с кодировкой... не разбираюсь...

Comment: Уважаемый  Fat-Zer, спасибо Вам большое! Ваш ответ, как всегда четкий, полезный и продуктивный! Это ответ НАСТОЯЩЕГО ПРОГРАММИСТА!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, одно удовольствие отвечать на такие детально сформулированные вопросы. А также очень приятно, когда они повторяются много раз.

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос??? Фантастика! НАСТОЯЩИЙ ПРОГРАММИСТ переспрашивает, что такое command-line shell. Я так понимаю, Ваша цель, это набивание себе рейтинга.

Comment: Есть десяток с лишним различных оболочек, а вот CLI'шный sqlite'овский клиент у меня так назвать язык не поворачивается, поэтому уточнить, что вкладывается в это понятие ИМХО было бы вполне резонно. И это не ответ, а уточняющий комментарий... Ответ на вопрос даст кто-нибудь ещё, кто разбирается в виндовых проблемах...