# как поменять кодовую страницу в Command Line Shell

Tags: sqlite3

Здравствуйте! **chcp 65001** - команда для CMD, меняющая кодовую на UTF8. Вопрос: есть ли такая команда для Command Line Shell For SQLite? Если я пытаюсь вставить данные из Command Line Shell

```
INSERT INTO Words (en, ru) VALUES
('one', 'один'),
('two', 'два'),
('three', 'три'),
('four', 'четыре'),
('five', 'пять');
```

то русские слова записываются в базу в виде вопросов. Я думаю, одно из решений этого вопроса, изменить кодовую страницу ***САМОЙ КОММАНДНОЙ ОБОЛОЧКИ***. `PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";` ничего не меняет.  Если кто знает, подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SQLite SELECT \* FROM кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770965/sqlite-select-from-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Уважаемый  Fat-Zer, спасибо Вам большое! Ваш ответ, как всегда четкий, полезный и продуктивный! Это ответ НАСТОЯЩЕГО ПРОГРАММИСТА!